# Append to Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, append

I'm trying to do a very easy task, add an item to a dictionary using "append".

This is the dict:

```
var myDictionary: [String:Int] = [
"Apple" : 1,
"Banana" : 2,
"Strawberry" : 3
]
```

I've tried this
`myDictionary+=["Raspberry":4]`
Here I get the error message:

> binary operator cannot be apllied to two operands

and also I tried:
`myDictionary.append("Raspberry":4)`

and

`myDictionary.append[("Raspberry":4)]`

as well, but I get the error that it has :

> no member 'append.

What exactly is the problem, how could I add the 4th item ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113 ? *"Accessing and Modifying a Dictionary ... You can add a new item to a dictionary with subscript syntax."*, with examples.

Answer (score 4):

`append` is the wrong tool here. You just want to set the value:

```
myDictionary["Raspberry"] = 4
```

`append` applies to things that conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection`. `Dictionary` does not. When you insert new things into a dictionary, they are not being appended to the end. They're being inserted into the appropriate buckets (perhaps replacing things already in place). If you use `append` to add something, you should reasonably expect `last` to then return that thing, but that's not promised (or even very likely) in a dictionary. `Set` is similar, and also has no `append`.